# Compare an array with a "very large" table of a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server

In an C# program I have an array with about 100.000 elements.

Then I have a SQL Server 2008 table where the primary key column contains more or less nearly all elements of the array (but a few not). The table can have up to 30.000.000 rows.

Now I want to determine which elements of the array do not exist in the table. How can this be achieved efficiently?

Comment: Are all the local IDs completely random, or do they occur in relatively decent sized consecutive groups?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most efficient method would probably be to bulk-insert those 100,000 elements into a temp table and then perform the comparison within the database itself.

(Note that I haven't tested this theory; it's just an educated guess.)

Comment: +1 the server will be faster, the DB better at indexing, and most importantly it is cheaper to move 100K elements to the server than 30M elements to the C# process.  That said, DBA's might frown on the approach.

Comment: Is there any reason for bulk inserting the records rather than just creating a massive WHERE IN(,,,) ?

Comment: The `WHERE IN` approach will yield a list of 100,000 ID's.  If they're all 6 digit numbers, the SQL string for the IN clause will be 700,000 characters long.  You may find that submitting a query that large fails.

Comment: @Rob: I think there's a limit to the number of items allowed per `IN` clause, as well as the overall batch size (although I can't remember what those limits are). However this is definitely an approach worth benchmarking. Even if you have to split it into 20 or 50 or 100 separate queries, it's possible that it might perform better than a single bulk-insert/query combo, although I suspect not.

Answer (score 1):

Query the table with a

```
select <primarykey> where <primarykey> in (<primary key of ur list of elements in c#>)
```

This should be faster than inserting all rows into a table and then checking with an except/minus command for missing elements, because it does not involve any write operation.

Once you have the list of primary keys which are common..pull it back into c# and compare.

Answer (score 0):

A way to avoid creating temp tables would be to use a stored procedure which accepts a table valued parameter of a user-defined table type (udtt). This table would have a schema of one column of a data type matching that in your array.

If you populate a DataTable (with a schema matching the udtt schema) with your array values and supply the data table as your stored proc's parameter, you can pass up all 100,000 of your items in their sql binary format. The proc can just do a join between the 30M row table and the table-valued parameter, returning the items in the TVP table with no matches in the master table.

This avoids needing to build massive `IN` statements.

**EDIT Regarding the comment from @Kyro below**

I'm now less confident in this approach. I found [an article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2338) showing the under-the-covers row-by-row inserts that Kyro describes. What you might gain in sending binary data over the network rather than a large TSQL `where in()` statement, may well be taken away by the performance SQL side. However, it's a fairly simple code approach, so might just be worth a quick test. Let us know how you get on?

Comment: This is the best answer in theory, although I've found TVPs to be unbelievably slow in practice. The OP should definitely benchmark the different suggested approaches and see which one works best for them and their particular setup.

Comment: Actually with 100,000 elements a table valued parameter will have very poor performance, especially if he is running against a database that is on a different machine. The reason is that it will be running 100,000 insert commands into that tabled value parameter. 

SqlBulkCopy will work better as he will be able to insert into a temp table (and if need be put an index on it) and then on the same connection run a simple sql statement such as 
   SELECT t.MyKey FROM #Temp t LEFT JOIN Source s on s.MeyKey = t.MyKey WHERE s.MyKey IS NULL

Then drop the temp table and close the connection.

Comment: @LukeH - We've found that the performance issue is helped by having an OPTION (RECOMPILE) statement at the end of the query. This was because TVPs don't have statistics, so SQL assumes TVPs to be holding one row for query optimisation purposes. The RECOMPILE generated a better plan, and reduced execution times from minutes to seconds.